# Episerver CMS, I want to post a simple notification using the CMS. I am not familiar with CMS.

Tags: javascript, css, content-management-system, episerver

Episerver CMS, I want to post a simple notification modal using the CMS. I am not familiar with CMS. Is there some websites which could guide me in understanding how Episerver CMS work. in posting new content as well as new modal to the mobile website

Comment: In what context? If you're looking to customize the edit interface UI, you'll need to familiarize yourself with the Dojo JavaScript framework, as the entire edit mode UI is based on it.

Answer (score 1):

You should get all the info you need from this site: http://world.episerver.com/documentation/cms/